# What Is The Name of this Washer?

Tags: plumbing, taps

I have changed the cartridge on a tap and in the process have ruined the washer that sits between the very base of the tap and the sink, I am referring to the ring at the base in this image which is now split:

[image: Tap base]

As a consequence water can now run below the tap and to the cupboard below. I don’t know what the name of the washer is below the tap, nor whether or not I’m likely to be able to source a replacement (I am aware that plumbers seem to suggest simply to replace the tap in situations such as this).

I don’t know the brand or model of the tap as it was installed in my house since new.

Comment: Those are specific to the brand and model of faucet, you will need to determine the make and model to source an in-kind replacement. Various companies name it differently but "desk gasket" (as suggested by @jsotola) is as good a generic term as any. You may be able to slap a rubber o-ring on there if you can't find an exact replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google `moen single handle faucet parts`

I found two terms

`escutcheon gasket` and `deck gasket`